# remove null elements from list ansible

Tags: json, list, ansible, null, jmespath

Below is my JSON file:

```json
[
   {
      "?xml": {
         "attributes": {
            "encoding": "UTF-8",
            "version": "1.0"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "domain": [

         {
            "server": [
               {
                  "name": "myserv1"
               },
               {
                  "ssl": {
                     "name": "myserv1"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "log": [
                     {
                        "name": "myserv1"
                     },
                     {
                        "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "server": [
               {
                  "name": "myserv2"
               },
               {
                  "ssl": {
                     "name": "myserv2"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "log": [
                     {
                        "name": "myserv2"
                     },
                     {
                        "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here is my Ansible play that uses JMESPath query to read the json data.

```yaml
- name: Server Names and log details
  set_fact:
    serverlog:  "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: '[].domain[].server[*].log[*].[name, "file-name"]'

- name: removing empty
  set_fact:
    serverlog:  "{{ serverlog|reject('match', '^$')|list }}"

- name: Print all server names with log details
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ serverlog }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Print all server names with log details] *********************************
Wednesday 02 March 2022  03:17:45 -0600 (0:00:00.100)       0:00:04.730 *******
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[[['myserv1', None], [None, '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log']]]) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            [
                "myserv1",
                null
            ],
            [
                null,
                "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I wish to remove null from the output so that the variables are better formatted & easily accessible.

I wish to store the read data as Ansible variables in a file like below:

```yaml
myserv1_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
myserv2_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
```

As you can see in the playbook I tried to remove the `null` in the playbook but it does not help.

Comment: Your json data structure can hardly be worse. The real solution is to fix whatever produces that litany of list of single element dict of list of single element dict.... With your current data, rather than trying to remove null values, the best way is to not generate them. If this can help => `"{{ jsondata | selectattr('domain', 'defined') | map(attribute='domain') | flatten | map(attribute='server') | flatten | selectattr('log', 'defined') | map(attribute='log') | map('combine') }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator i tried your suggestion but i get this error `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'server'\n\nThe error appears to be in....`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve most of what you are looking for with this — quite complex — JMESPath query:

```
[].domain[].server[?log].log[].{
  name: join(`_`, [[?name].name | [0], `log`]), 
  filename: [?"file-name"]."file-name" | [0]
}
```

The trick here is to query the `server` list to find elements that do have a property `log` — with the help of `server[?log]`, then in the `log` list, do the same for element that have a property `name` and a property `file-name` with `[?name]` and `[?"file-name"]` respectively.

Because those are lists, you will need to stop the projections with a [pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions), before getting the first item of both those lists — so, with a construct like `| [0]`.

In order to add the `_log` suffix, you can use the [`join`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) function, by creating an array of two element, containing the `name` and the string `log`, that would be joined with an underscore: `` join(`_`, [[?name].name | [0], `log`]) ``.

With all that, you end up with this list:

```json
- filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log
  name: myserv1_log
- filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log
  name: myserv2_log
```

And now, we just need to make that a dictionary, with the help of [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries).

All this together gives this `set_fact` task:

```yaml
- set_fact:
  server_logs: >-
    {{
      jsondata | json_query('[].domain[].server[?log].log[].{
        name: join(`_`, [[?name].name | [0], `log`]), 
        filename: [?"file-name"]."file-name" | [0]
      }') | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='filename')
    }}
```

Which would yield, if `debug`'ed:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  server_logs:
    myserv1_log: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log
    myserv2_log: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log
```

Comment: I get this error while trying your solution: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nIn function join(), invalid type for value: myserv1, expected one of: ['array-string'], received: \"AnsibleUnsafeText\""}
`

Comment: Should i put a fresh post for this?