# unable to ideally parse a json file in ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, null, jmespath

Below is my sample JSON file.

```
[
   {
      "?xml": {
         "attributes": {
            "encoding": "UTF-8",
            "version": "1.0"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "domain": [

         {
            "server": [
               {
                  "name": "myserv1"
               },
               {
                  "ssl": {
                     "name": "myserv1"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "log": [
                     {
                        "name": "myserv1"
                     },
                     {
                        "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "server": [
               {
                  "name": "myserv2"
               },
               {
                  "ssl": {
                     "name": "myserv2"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "log": [
                     {
                        "name": "myserv2"
                     },
                     {
                        "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My requirement is to read the json file and store the value in a file like below:

```
myserv1_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
myserv2_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
```

i.e

```
<server>_log: <file-name>
```

Here is my Ansible play that uses JMESPath query to read the json data.

```
- name: Server Names and log details
  set_fact:
    serverlog:  "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: '[].domain[].server[*].log[*].[name, "file-name"]'

- name: Print all server names with log details
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ serverlog }}"
```

As you can see I get several `null` values in the output

output:

```
TASK [Print all server names with log details] *********************************
Wednesday 02 March 2022  03:17:45 -0600 (0:00:00.100)       0:00:04.730 *******
ok: [localhost] => (item=[]) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[[['myserv1', None], [None, '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log']]]) => {
    "msg": [
        [
            [
                "myserv1",
                null
            ],
            [
                null,
                "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I tied to get rid of the `null` using the below but that too does not get me the desired output:

```
 - name: test
   set_fact:
     list2: "{{list2  + [item]}}"
   when: item != "null"
   with_items:
     - "{{serverlog}}"

 - name: Neww Print all server names with log details
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   with_items:
     - "{{ list3 }}"
```

I also tried the solution proposed on StackOverflow but I get error:

```
"{{ jsondata | selectattr('domain', 'defined') | map(attribute='domain') | flatten | map(attribute='server') | flatten | selectattr('log', 'defined') | map(attribute='log') | map('combine') }}"
```

Output error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'server'\n\nThe error appears to be in....
```

Any earlier similar post did not get any working solution is why I decided to post here:

[remove null elements from list ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320672/remove-null-elements-from-list-ansible)

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the structure of your json is always the same no need to use jmepath:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ servername }} --> filename: {{ filename }}"
      loop: "{{ json[1].domain }}"
      vars:
        servername: "{{ item.server.0.name }}_log"
        filename: "{{ item['server'][2]['log'][1]['file-name'] }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'myserv1'}}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "name: myserv1_log --> filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'myserv2'}}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "name: myserv2_log --> filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
}
```

some explanations:
json is an array with 2 records one with key `?xml` the other with key `domain`

`domain` is an array with key `server`

`server` is an array witk the differents keys `name, ssl and log`

`log` is an array with differents keys `name and file-name`

---

`json[1].domain` just keeps the part containing domain, json[0] contains the header of json

`item.server.0.name (= item['server'][0]['name'])` is the first item of record server which contains the key `name`

`item['server'][2]['log'][1]['file-name']`  is the third item for a record server which contains the key `log` and the second item of log contains the key `file-name`

Comment: can you please explain the numerics and how to determine them here `item.server.0.name` & `item.server.2.log[1]['file-name']` the `0,2,1`?

Comment: i add some explanations in my answer

Comment: if `server` would have been the 4th key in array `domain` then what would change to get the same results ? `item.server.0.name` & `  item.server.2.log[1]['file-name']` would change to what ?

Comment: you could add :   `when: item.server is defined`  and that dont change the other values...  if you dont know how to do , i suggest you to open a new question with your other structure of json

Comment: i opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71475931/how-to-deal-with-missing-keys-in-json-array-when-reading-in-ansible