# how to deal with missing keys in JSON array when reading in Ansible

Tags: json, arraylist, dynamic, ansible, key

Below is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "?xml": {
      "attributes": {
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "domain": [
      {
        "name": "mydom"
      },
      {
        "domain-version": "12.2.1.3.0"
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "AdminServer"
          },
          {
            "ssl": {
              "name": "AdminServer"
            }
          },
          {
            "listen-port": "12400"
          },
          {
            "listen-address": "mydom.host1.bank.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "myserv1"
          },
          {
            "ssl": [
              {
                "name": "myserv1"
              },
              {
                "login-timeout-millis": "25000"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "log": [
              {
                "name": "myserv1"
              },
              {
                "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "myserv2"
          },
          {
            "ssl": {
              "name": "myserv2"
            }
          },
         {
           "reverse-dns-allowed": "false"
         },
          {
            "log": [
              {
                "name": "myserv2"
              },
              {
                "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get log list's `name` and `file-name` like below using ansible code.

```
myserv1_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
myserv2_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
```

There are two challenges that i m facing.

1. `server` may not always be the 3rd key of `domain` array.
2. `log` array may not alway be a key for all `server` arrays and thus should not be printed. For example. `server` name AdminServer does not have any `log` list while myserv1 & myserv2 do have.

I need an ansible code to print the desired for the dynamically changing json.

Note: `server` will always be a key in the `domain` array

I'm posting with reference to my similar query here: [unable to ideally parse a json file in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463011/unable-to-ideally-parse-a-json-file-in-ansible/71467691?noredirect=1#comment126329169_71467691)

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Unless the participants from your other question show up and bring all that context with them, you'll get better results by paying attention to the [MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the how-to-ask guide. What error are you getting from your own attempt, and what is the expected outcome if some magic wand solved your problem? Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just test if both keys exist:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ servername }} --> filename: {{ filename }}"
      loop: "{{ json[1].domain }}"
      vars:
        servername: "{{ item.server.0.name }}_log"
        filename: "{{ item['server'][2]['log'][1]['file-name'] }}"
      when: item.server is defined and item.server.2.log is defined
```

result:

```
TASK [display] 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'USWL1212MRSHM01'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'domain-version': '12.2.1.3.0'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'AdminServer'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'AdminServer'}}, {'listen-port': '12400'}, {'listen-address': 'myhost1'}]}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'myserv1'}}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "name: myserv1_log --> filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'myserv2'}}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "name: myserv2_log --> filename: /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
}
```

As you can see, when the condition is not true, the action is skipped...

you could simplify by testing only key `log`, because in your case, key`log` is always linked to key `server`

```
when: item.server.2.log is defined
```

Comment: i dont know why you have an error, i have fixed your json, because there is a bad `{` after `"domain":[` , have you just tested my playbook?

Comment: I dont have error anymore @Frenchy however, can u suggest if `log` list not always the second element of server array? i have updated the JSON in the original post to have `log` list as the 2nd array element for first server block and 3rd array element for second server block.

Comment: my answer is for your primary question, so if you change the logic of your question,....the answer has to be changed...

Comment: I will make a fresh post as the question has changed.

Comment: please ask correctly your question to have all case you could meet

Comment: Sure, i have posted the new query here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478733/how-to-grab-json-array-element-having-dynamically-changing-position-in-ansible