# How to grab Json array element having dynamically changing position in Ansible

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, ansible, element

Below is my json file where i have `log` array inside `server` array which is inside `domain` array.

```
[
  {
    "?xml": {
      "attributes": {
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "version": "1.0"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "domain": [
      {
        "name": "mydom"
      },
      {
        "domain-version": "12.2.1.3.0"
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "AdminServer"
          },
          {
            "ssl": {
              "name": "AdminServer"
            }
          },
          {
            "listen-port": "12400"
          },
          {
            "listen-address": "mydom.host1.bank.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "myserv1"
          },
          {
            "ssl": [
              {
                "name": "myserv1"
              },
              {
                "login-timeout-millis": "25000"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "log": [
              {
                "name": "myserv1"
              },
              {
                "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "server": [
          {
            "name": "myserv2"
          },
          {
            "ssl": {
              "name": "myserv2"
            }
          },
         {
           "reverse-dns-allowed": "false"
         },
          {
            "log": [
              {
                "name": "myserv2"
              },
              {
                "file-name": "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The position of `log` array inside `server` array may change as shown in the json above.

I wish to grab the output as below:

```
myserv1_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
myserv2_log: "/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
```

There are two challenges that i m facing.

1. `server` may not always be the 3rd key of `domain` array.
2. `log` array may not alway be a key for all server arrays and thus should not be printed. For example. server name AdminServer does not have any log list while myserv1 & myserv2 do have.

Also, `log` if present may not always be the 2nd key of `server` array as seen in the json.

A solution for when log is always the second element of `server` aarray was provided as below:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ servername }} --> filename: {{ filename }}"
      loop: "{{ json[1].domain }}"
      vars:
        servername: "{{ item.server.0.name }}_log"
        filename: "{{ item['server'][2]['log'][1]['file-name'] }}"
      when: item.server is defined and item.server.2.log is defined
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: the name is the name inside server array not the name inside log array? you confirm?

Comment: The name is the name inside `server` array not the name inside `log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lot of solutions to do that, one :

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "{{ server.0.name }} -> {{ filename.0.log[1]['file-name'] }}"
      loop: "{{ json[1].domain }}"
      vars:
        server: "{{ item.server | selectattr('name', 'defined') }}"
        filename:  "{{ item.server | selectattr('log', 'defined') }}"
      when: item.server is defined and (item.server | selectattr('log', 'defined')) != []
```

result:

```
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'mydom'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'domain-version': '12.2.1.3.0'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'AdminServer'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'AdminServer'}}, {'listen-port': '12400'}, {'listen-address': 'mydom.host1.bank.com'}]}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'ssl': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'login-timeout-millis': '25000'}]}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv1'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "myserv1 -> /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv1/myserv1.log"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'ssl': {'name': 'myserv2'}}, {'reverse-dns-allowed': 'false'}, {'log': [{'name': 'myserv2'}, {'file-name': '/web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log'}]}]}) => {
    "msg": "myserv2 -> /web/bea_logs/domains/mydom/myserv2/myserv2.log"
}
```

despite your problem, try this another solution:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    json: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: display
      set_fact:
        values: "{{ values | d([]) + [v] }}"
      loop: "{{ json[1].domain }}"
      vars:
        v: >-
          {%- set dico = (item | dict2items).0.value -%}
          {%- set result = {} -%}
          {%- for i in dico -%}
          {%- for x in i if x in ["name", "log"] -%}
          {%- if result.update({x: i[x]}) -%}{% endif -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {%- if 'log' in result %}{{ result }}{% endif -%}
      when: item.server is defined and v != ''
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }} -> {{ item.log[1]['file-name'] }}"
      loop: "{{ values }}"
```

Comment: i get this error trying your solution `"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/test.yml': line 29, column 8`. should I say `ignore_errors: true`

Comment: are you sure to use my playbook with the right name json? i show the complete code

Comment: i m using the same json and your play (copied & pasted). `ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0]`

Comment: i am in version ansible 2.12..  but i dont see why you have an error...

Comment: i made a few seconds video showcasing the error so we are sure I am making no mistakes: https://youtu.be/1HpKAIbSXds

Comment: Any other solution that may work with the latest ansible @Frenchy?

Comment: maybe the selectattr are not funvctional with your version of ansible

Comment: Could we have a solution apart from `selectattr` ?

Comment: i am looking... we could use a customfilter?

Comment: I have never used a custom filter before but if it is easy and straight forward I'm fine until we find an alternate solution.

Comment: Meanwhile i submitted this issue as a bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/77288

Comment: try my another solution, i am using jinja2 instead of custom filter..

Comment: it works but i m finding it a bit tricky to understand and then I have to leverage the same logic for other attributes of the json file. Could you please drop some debugs and explanation on how the logic works?

Comment: I upgraded my ansible and your initial solution works. Kudos for being in the community @Frenchy !! I would request your jinja solution posted here as well